# How to break up document by sentences with Spacy

Tags: python, spacy, sentence, text-segmentation

How can I break a document (e.g., paragraph, book, etc) into sentences.

For example, `"The dog ran. The cat jumped"` into `["The dog ran", "The cat jumped"]`  with spacy?

Comment: with basic python: `my_string.split(".")`

Comment: @Julien see the updated question. I did not mean literally "The dog ran. The cat jumped". Consider "Mr. Baxter ate a pickle."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The up-to-date answer is this:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
from spacy.lang.en import English # updated

raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe('sentencizer')
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.text.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Comment: If there is an etc. in a sentence it fails.

Comment: This uses the rule-based method, rather than the statistical model to split sentences. For my use case, using `en_core_web_sm` worked better, and `en_core_web_lg` better yet, and fast enough for my needs. See [KB_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61254146/1343535).

Comment: Actually in spacy 3.0 the syntax is now `nlp.add_pipe('sentencizer')` as @user8189050 notes.

Comment: spacy 3.0.6: Change `sent.string.strip()` to `sent.text.strip()`

Answer (score 27):

**Answer**

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

text = 'My first birthday was great. My 2. was even better.'
sentences = [i for i in nlp(text).sents]
```

**Additional info**
This assumes that you have already installed the model "en_core_web_sm" on your system. If not, you can easily install it by running the following command in your terminal:

```
$ python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

(See [here](https://spacy.io/models) for an overview of all available models.)

Depending on your data this can lead to better results than just using `spacy.lang.en.English`. One (very simple) comparison example:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp_simple = English()
nlp_simple.add_pipe(nlp_simple.create_pipe('sentencizer'))

nlp_better = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')


text = 'My first birthday was great. My 2. was even better.'

for nlp in [nlp_simple, nlp_better]:
    for i in nlp(text).sents:
        print(i)
    print('-' * 20)
```

Outputs:

```
>>> My first birthday was great.
>>> My 2.
>>> was even better.
>>> --------------------
>>> My first birthday was great.
>>> My 2. was even better.
>>> --------------------
```

Answer (score 17):

With spacy 3.0.1 they changed the pipline.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English 

nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe('sentencizer')


def split_in_sentences(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    return [str(sent).strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as of spacy 3.0

Comment: What if the language is not English?

Answer (score 14):

From [spacy's github support page](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/93#issuecomment-138773719)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
from spacy.en import English

raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
nlp = English()
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Comment: This answer is outdated as of 2019 (SpaCy 2.1.8). npit@ answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

**For current versions (e.g. 3.x and above) use the code below for optimal results with the statistical model** rather than the rule based `sentencizer` component.

Also note that you can **speed up processing and reduce the memory footprint** if you include only the pipeline components that are needed for sentence separation.

```
import spacy

# instantiate pipeline with any model of your choosing
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = "The dog ran. The cat jumped. The 2. fox hides behind the house."

# only select necessary pipeline components to speed up processing
with nlp.select_pipes(enable=['tok2vec', "parser", "senter"]):
    doc = nlp(text)
    
for sentence in doc.sents:
    print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated to reflect the comments in the first answer

```
from spacy.lang.en import English

raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe('sentencizer')
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.text.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```