# how to explode a list of strings while keeping the other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,3],
                   'col2' : ['A','B','C'],
                   'paragraph': ['sentence one. sentence two',
                                 'sentence three. and sentence four',
                                 'crazy sentence!! and the final one.']})

df
Out[11]: 
   col1 col2                            paragraph
0     1    A           sentence one. sentence two
1     2    B    sentence three. and sentence four
2     3    C  crazy sentence!! and the final one.
```

I would like to split the paragaphs into sentences (using `spacy` preferably) but I need to keep the information in the other columns.

I know how to explode the column and split (naively) on `.`

```
df.paragraph.str.split('.').explode()
Out[10]: 
0                          sentence one
0                          sentence two
1                        sentence three
1                     and sentence four
2    crazy sentence!! and the final one
2                                      
Name: paragraph, dtype: object
```

but this loses the information in `col1` and `col2` (those should be kept and repeated in the sentence-by-sentence dataframe) and does not split correctly the sentence with an exclamation mark.

Using Spacy and `nlp(paragraph).sents` will still loses the two columns.

What can I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer SpaCy to split text into sentences, use

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe('sentencizer')

def split_in_sentences(text):
    return [sent.text.strip() for sent in nlp(text).sents]

df['paragraph'] = df['paragraph'].apply(split_in_sentences)
>>> df.explode('paragraph')
   col1 col2           paragraph
0     1    A       sentence one.
0     1    A        sentence two
1     2    B     sentence three.
1     2    B   and sentence four
2     3    C    crazy sentence!!
2     3    C  and the final one.
```

See the [How to break up document by sentences with Spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66009264/3832970) SO post.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two steps:

```
df['paragraph'] = df['paragraph'].str.split('.')
df.explode('paragraph')
```

output:

```
   col1 col2                           paragraph
0     1    A                        sentence one
0     1    A                        sentence two
1     2    B                      sentence three
1     2    B                   and sentence four
2     3    C  crazy sentence!! and the final one
2     3    C
```

To split on both `.`/`!`:

```
df['paragraph'] = df['paragraph'].str.split('[.!]+')
df.explode('paragraph')
```

```
   col1 col2           paragraph
0     1    A        sentence one
0     1    A        sentence two
1     2    B      sentence three
1     2    B   and sentence four
2     3    C      crazy sentence
2     3    C   and the final one
2     3    C
```

Comment: thanks. This works but does not split the sentence with the !. I think for this `spacy` is needed

Answer (score 1):

Define your extend as a separate temporary dataframe and use it to join the main dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,3],
               'col2' : ['A','B','C'],
               'paragraph': ['sentence one. sentence two',
                             'sentence three. and sentence four',
                             'crazy sentence!! and the final one.']})
alfa = pd.DataFrame(df.paragraph.str.split('.').explode())
alfa.rename(columns={"paragraph":"paragraphSplit"},inplace=True)
alfa.join(df)
```

| paragraphSplit | col1 | col2 | paragraph |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sentence one | 1 | A | sentence one. sentence two |
| sentence two | 1 | A | sentence one. sentence two |
| sentence three | 2 | B | sentence three. and sentence four |
| and sentence four | 2 | B | sentence three. and sentence four |
| crazy sentence!! and the final one | 3 | C | crazy sentence!! and the final one. |
|  | 3 | C | crazy sentence!! and the final one. |

Hope this is what you are looking for.